# Addition through linear indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing, octave, addition

I have a 256 x 256 matrix M, and have produced some linear indexes L.

Also I have a vector of weights, of numels same as L, to be added to the elements of M indexed by L.
Problem is, with the expression

```
M(L) = M(L) + weights;
```

For duplicate values in L, only the last corresponding element in weights will be added.

Is there a simple way to resolve this/am I missing something?

Comment: the pseudo code you wrote works for me. See that you don't overwrite `weights` or `L` somewhere before...

Comment: @nate Try running this: `X = [1; 1]; L = [1 1 2]; W = 10 * ones(length(L), 1); X(L) = X(L) + W;`. I think the behavior the OP is trying to obtain is that `X` should end up with first element equal to `21` and second element equal to `11`. But the code I provided yields both elements equal to `11`. Interesting problem! Cheers.

Comment: @ColinTBowers
yeah, that.
COuld there be a workaround method,maybe  with unique() to sum up all relative elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way to go here is using accumarray:

```
% The 'data'
M = zeros(10,5); % Suppose this is your matrix
L = [46 47 47 46 48 49 48 48 48]'; % The linear index numbers
weights = [4 7 4 6 4 9 48 8 48]'; % The weights for these index numbers

% Make sure the indices are in ascending order
Y = SORTROWS([L weights]);

% Determining the weights to be added
idx = unique(Y(:,1));
weights_unique = accumarray(Y(:,1),Y(:,2));

% The addition
M(idx) = M(idx) + weights_unique(weights_unique>0);
```

Comment: Wow,that's exactly it.I've been trying to make this manually and without for loops and i was getting desperate.
thanks so much!

Comment: I have updated the answer to make sure that it also works if your index is not sorted in advance.

Comment: Would there be any reason for a mismatch at the resulting weights length and the unique(indices) ?

Comment: yes, if your `L` would be `[3 3 2 2 2 1]` my original code would fail as `unique` includes a sorting step, but `accumarray` does not.

Comment: @DennisJaherudin 
I'm trying to use accumarray for two same size vectors L,W.
Even with sorting i end up with different numels for unique(L) and the result of accumarray.
Testing L and W with other partner vectors works though.

Any advice?

Comment: @DennisJaherudin
Please try accumarray with the following indices:
`L = [46    47    47    46    48    49    48    48    48]`

For some reason i keep getting numel(unique_weights ) = 49 (yeah, with sorting them first)

Comment: Apparently it only worked if all indices were used, I have now updated it to match your vector.